# 2 separate audio outputs sample player

Tags: audio

I'm looking to (hopefully) create a sample player that will be capable of playing 2 wav samples at once. One out of one stereo out and one out of another. (To send one to a stereo mix in a sound desk and one to a drummers headphones). (Using a pi3)

Does anyone know if there's any hardware that fits on the pi itself that can split the audio in this way?

Or would I have to use an external USB interface and the pi as a computer (like I do at the moment with a laptop and daw)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem would lie in the simultaneous playback of 2 audio files rather than the 2 separate outputs. A simple usb audio interface for 2$ would sove the latter - or you can use the GPIO card designed for the PI.

But if you solve the first problem let me know!!! :-)